# Can you sell apps as a Google Developer or must you be a Merchant?

Tags: android

Apologies if this is not a typical SO question, but I'm hoping that someone in the same situation will be able to help.

In some countries you cannot open a Google Merchant account, but you can open a Google Developer account. So, if you open a Google Developer account, but not have the ability to open a Merchant account, will you still be able to sell your apps or only give them away for free?

I'm asking because I've only ever developed for clients who sold their apps, but never sold an app myself and in my country (South Africa) you cannot register as a Google Merchant.

**UPDATE:**

For those listed outside of the countries below in my answer, take note that [the Amazon Android developers](https://developer.amazon.com/welcome.html) does not currently have such a limitation, and that developer registration is currently free (at the time or writing). Payment is done by means of cheque.

Comment: From reading [this](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188493&topic=2493029&ctx=topic), I don't think Google Merchant is necessary for selling apps on Google Play. It looks like it has more to do with online retail.

Comment: Careful with Amazon, they choose the price they sell your app at, only using your set price as a guide. Read this: http://www.insidemobileapps.com/2011/04/14/igda-warns-against-amazon-appstores-pricing-terms-but-doesnt-mention-in-app-payments/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, it cost me 25 US dollars to find out that being a Google developer does not entitle you to sell your apps. A registered developer can only publish free apps. You need to be a merchant to charge for applications.

This was the first thing I saw after logging in and following a link to 'sell your app':

> Supported locations for merchants
>
> Currently, developers in the below countries may register as Google
>   Checkout merchants and sell paid applications:
>
> ```
> Argentina*
> Australia
> Austria
> Belgium
> Brazil*
> Canada
> Czech Republic
> Denmark
> Finland
> France
> Germany
> Hong Kong
> Ireland
> Israel
> Italy
> Japan
> Mexico
> Netherlands
> New Zealand
> Norway
> Poland
> Portugal
> Russia*
> Singapore
> Spain
> South Korea
> Sweden
> Switzerland
> Taiwan*
> United Kingdom
> United States
> ```
>
> We're working hard to add more countries, but we're unable to provide
>   any guidance on timelines. Please stay tuned!

I just hope they use my 25 dollars wisely - that's good beer money.

**Update:**

I contacted Google support and they confirmed that you need to be a registered merchant to sell android applications.

Comment: Good for me to see this post! Saved me 25 dollars thx

Comment: @SerdarS. I updated my question. You can register for free with Amazon at the moment. It's better than nothing :-)

Comment: @JacobusR what is your feedback about Amazon for selling android apps?

Comment: Hi @Md.NaushadAlam, I tried the Amazon option also, but although they allow you to register as a developer, payment seems to be the problem. After registration they will probably notify you that you won't receive any payment for your app until you register according to their tax laws, so this could be a big schlep or even impossible depending on your circumstance. Most freelance or hobbyist android developers just want to write apps. They don't have the time or capacity to learn foreign country tax laws.

Comment: @JacobusR, Thanks for the nice replay and you are right that developers only want to build app but not involve in administrative or laws related functions.

Answer (score 7):

I am a registered Google Developer with Paid apps for sale. It is not possible to sell paid apps without a Google Merchant Account as it handles all payments. You can, however, still offer free apps.

Edit: Also it is possible to monetize your free apps through ads and such still.

Comment: Bit of a cheek that they charge for developer registration, but not allowing you to monetize your app - and NO, not all apps can be monitized through ads.